# system function doesn't work

Tags: php, path, system

I want to execute an [application](http://interfaces.gams-software.com/doku.php?id=env%3aspawning_gams_from_php) which is gams in php I insert the path file location below
It shows error how can I correct it?

```
$modelfile = 'trnsport_php.gms';
if (!system('C:/Documents and Settings/Parsa/My Documents/gamsdir/projdir'.$modelfile.' lo=2')) {
  print "error";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a Windows system. Shouldn't / be \ ?

Comment: Yes,I tried \ too but no result

Answer (score 1):

You should add a "/" after

```
!system('C:/Documents and Settings/Parsa/My Documents/gamsdir/projdir
```

Comment: Thanks No It doesn't work I found new things I was in a big mistake it is like running in shell so I asked this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326633/execute-exe-file-from-an-application-with-system

Comment: You might want to use "if system(...) === FALSE" since it outputs a boolean FALSE on error. !(system(...)) might also evaluate to true when system returns an empty line or "0".