# execute exe file from an application with system

Tags: php, system

I have a Gams [application](http://interfaces.gams-software.com/doku.php?id=env%3aspawning_gams_from_php) which I want to run it through php code
after trying many things finally I found that for running in commmand line I should go to `C:\Program Files\GAMS23.7` run a command in commandline for running the application as follows:

```
gams.exe trnsport_php.gms
```

the Gams wil be run successfully in commandline now I wanted to run it in php I added an alias with this path

> C:\Program Files\GAMS23.7

and then I created my php file in there
when I want to exacute it with this code in php:

```
if(system('gams.exe trnsport_php.gms'))
echo 'Not Error';
else echo'Error';
```

it shows me Error

and again using this one:

```
if(system('./gams.exe trnsport_php.gms'))
echo 'Not Error';
else echo'Error';
```

has printed again Error

I tried exec too but no result I don't know what is wrong here.
this one also doesn't work:

```
if(system ("\"C:\\Program Files\\GAMS23.7\\gams.exe \"C:\\Program Files\\GAMS23.7\\trnsport_php.gms"))
echo'success';
else
echo 'no';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I don't know why but I should go to commandline and simply call the gams

```
echo exec('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe');
echo exec('gams.exe trnsport_php.gms');
```

Answer (score 0):

`system` and `exec` command returns `false` on failure and last line from the result of executed command on success. To test if command runs successfuly, you have to use it like this:

```
if (system('./gams.exe trnsport_php.gms') === FALSE)
  echo 'error';
else
  echo 'success';
```

If you don't use `=== FALSE`, you will see 'Error' also if no output is produced.

Maybe try using `passthru` to see raw output of executed command.

Comment: Thank you it shows me success but it doesn't work because when running,it should make a text file,but it didn't make it! so It doesn't execute:-?

Comment: well no matter using ==false it is mistaken! it is == not === so it sends me error execution is denied

Comment: `===` checks also variable type, while `0 == '0'` returns TRUE, `0 === '0'` returns FALSE. Check file permissions on `gams.exe`.

Comment: how should I check I have windows operating system